# How to use dplyr to recode all values that are not in a list of values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a list of names I want to keep, the rest I want to recode to `"Other"`.

```
namesToKeep = data.frame(
  car = c("Merc 240D", "Cadillac Fleetwood"),
  reason = c("Great car","Me like")
)

selectedCars <- namesToKeep$car
names(selectedCars) <- selectedCars

mtcars %>% mutate(CarName = rownames(mtcars)) %>%
  mutate(
    CarName = recode(CarName, !!!selectedCars, .default = "Other")
  )
```

The above code works, and demonstrates what I want to do. But I would like to clean it up a bit and not have to calculate a named vector of selected names before hand.

Using base R I can do this by directly mutating the dataframe but I wonder what is the idiomatic `dplry` way of doing this?

Comment: @akrun sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you.  What do you expect as a solution as `recode` is from `dplyr`

Comment: I want to be able to do all of it in one go without having to make `selectedCars` before hand. Above approach is messy in my opinion. I am hoping `recode` has some kind of support for saying "recode the stuff not in this list".

Comment: From what I can tell, `dplyr` is all about declarative manipulation of data. Having to create `selectedCars` is an imperative departure from that pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `deframe` function from `tibble` which can directly convert the data.frame to a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
mtcars %>%
      mutate(CarName = rownames(mtcars),
      CarName = recode(CarName, !!!deframe(namesToKeep), .default = "Other"))
```

---

If it is on the same column, use `setNames` to create the names on the fly

```
mtcars %>%
     mutate(CarName = rownames(.),
            CarName = recode(CarName, 
    !!! setNames(namesToKeep$car, namesToKeep$car), .default = "Other"))
```

---

Or a hacky option is to duplicate the column with indexing and then `deframe`

```
mtcars %>%
     mutate(CarName = rownames(.),
            CarName = recode(CarName, 
          !!! deframe(namesToKeep[c(1, 1)]), .default = "Other"))
```

Comment: That almost works. Only problem is it recodes the stuff I want unchanged. I think this is definitely the right direction to go though.

Comment: `!!!deframe(data.frame(namesToKeep$car, namesToKeep$car)),` works perfectly but I thik is not very clean

Comment: My earlier comment, was that it changes the car names to "Great car" and "Me like". Desired outcome is it leaves the car names unchanged.

Comment: Yes, named vector where names are the same as values would work well with `!!!` for this case.

Comment: @ChechyLevas for that you can use `setNames` i.e. `setNames(namesToKeep$car, namesToKeep$car)`

Comment: Nailed it! I will accept your answer, but probably worth editing it to make the ultimate solution clear.